# android installation error: duplicated package

Tags: android-emulator

I am trying to run a map based app, using `com.google.andoid.maps` however I get the following error:

```
[2012-06-03 17:12:43 - myGps] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PACKAGE
[2012-06-03 17:12:43 - myGps] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-06-03 17:12:43 - myGps] Launch canceled!
```

I have succeeded installing the package several times but the app wouldn't show on the emulator's screen, now I can't even install it.
I have tried:

1. Reseting adb
2. Installing manually
3. Checking if the package exists in ddms

None of these worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com.google.andoid.maps is the default google maps package.
Try giving a different package to your application.It should work then.

Comment: im not sure i follow i changed package to com.example and imported the needed class, it still wont work.